# Angular 1 updating values of a Select

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I hope there's still some Angular 1 guru around here ;)

**Description**

I have some checkboxes loaded via Ajax. The number, names, and status (checked/unchecked) data is loaded via ajax.

I also have many select (dropdown lists) fed by the checked checkboxes. For example, if I check the "Guitar" checkbox then my selects will have the "Guitar" option.

**The problem**

The selects don't shown any option until I manually uncheck and check again one of the checkboxes.

[image: form]

**Dirty workaround**

I found a workaround which is very very dirty and unreliable that is, calling $scope.$apply after a couple of seconds:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $scope.$apply(function () {
        $scope.table = {};

        if($scope.property.value.text) {
            $scope.table = JSON.parse($scope.property.value.text);

        }
        $scope.propertyChanged = function (property) {
            property.value = {
                text : JSON.stringify($scope.table)
            };
        }
    });
}, 2000)
```

I tried to call the $scope.$apply on the ajax callback but I get an error: `angular.js:10061 Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress.`

Any idea about how to avoid this workaround?

Comment: how are you loading your data? this seems that could be solved if you load the table/dropdows after your checkboxes are fully loaded.

Comment: ajax / $http is asynchronous, so use Promises and resolve them with `.then()`. So it's either `$http` or `$q`. Instead of chaining them, try `$q.all(promises)` if you have more than one asynchronous callback

Comment: @ElmerDantas I can't defer loading the table, all markeup is already in page

Comment: @AlekseySolovey Yep, I really know ajax is async. As I said I also tried to add the $scope.$apply inside the callback but I get the error I reported. I currently use $http and I placed the $scope.$apply inside my then()

Comment: @DarkoRomanov well timeout and apply are not needed if you resolve your promise; you already bind your variables to scope. (Also isn't the syntax is just `$scope.$apply()`, without anything inside it?)

Comment: @AlekseySolovey $apply can take a function as parameter https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply What do you mean by "resolving" a promise? Shouldn't .then() be enough?

Comment: It seems you are using some custom elements to render your page that's why you need to $apply manually. I will suggest using $scope.$applyAsync() once you get your data from $http.